# GetPixel Function Doesn't Work in Qt C++ LNK2019 undefined reference to __imp_GetPixel

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-c++, mingw

I tried to use some win32 function in Qt Application but all of them work except GetPixel function I tried to use MSVC 2019 compiler MSVC Compiler has problems with all the functions (error LNK2019) but when I added `win32:LIBS += -luser32` to the .pro file all of them work except GetPixel function,
here is my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wingdi.h> // For GetPixel

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    POINT p;
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, 0, 0);
    QString colorRGB = "background-color: rgb(255,0,0);";
    w.setStyleSheet(colorRGB);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
    return a.exec();
}
```

I want to use GetPixel function to get red value of a pixel in my browser and set it to background color of Qt

**Edit:** fixed by adding `win32:LIBS += -lGdi32` to .pro file

Comment: The documentation here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getpixel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getpixel) says you need to link to `Gdi32.lib`

Comment: @drescherjm how do I do it in Qt?

Comment: The same way you did for `user32.lib`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `win32:LIBS += -lGdi32` to .pro file